# Confused how to use argparse

Tags: python, argparse

I am trying to write a python script that can be run from the command line with

```
python script.py --input file.txt
```

or

```
python script.py -i file.txt
```

script.py will take in the file file.txt and open/read.

This is what I have so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="I'm not sure what I should write here.")
parser.add_argument('-i','--input', help='Input file name',required=True)
args = parser.parse_args()
```

Now...How do I actually access the input file?

What I want is to write to an output file, e.g. python script.py --outputfile file.csv? I do not understand how to interact with writing the file. Sorry if this is too easy.

Comment: You ask the parser for the name of the input file (that's all argparse is, a lump of the the options passed on the command line), and then open it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is pretty simple!

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Something like -- File reader: reads file line by line.")
parser.add_argument('-i','--input', help='Input file name',required=True)
args = parser.parse_args()

with open(args.input) as fp:
    for line in fp:
       print line
```

If you want to write some content to the input file. Open the file in write mode and write to it whatever you want.

```
with open(args.input, 'w') as fp:
    fp.write("Hello World!")
```

If you want a separate file to write, add an argument to your argparser in write mode and then write to it.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Something like -- File reader/writer: reads/writes files line by line.")
parser.add_argument('-i','--input', help='Input file name',required=True)
parser.add_argument('-o','--output', help='Output file name',type=argparse.FileType('w'),required=True)
args = parser.parse_args()

with open(args.input) as fp:
    for line in fp:
        print line

with open(args.output) as fp:
    fp.write("Hello World!")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can access the string the user enter after `-i` with:

```
args.input
```

For example:

```
argp_test.py  -i my_file_name.txt
```

Now:

```
print(args.input)
```

prints:

```
my_file_name.txt
```

Next step is to read the file content:

```
with open(args.input) as fobj:
    for line in fobj:
          # do something with this line
```

BTW, you got a syntax error in this line:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='I'm not sure what I should write here.')
```

It should look like this:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="I'm not sure what I should write here.")
```

When you use a `'` in your string, you need to use `"` at the begging and end of your string. So use:

```
"I'm not"
```

instead of:

```
'I'm not'
```